# Jest snapshot undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

i'm new to testing react with jest, and i'm confused as to why the snapshots that are generated keeps saying [undefined].

I feel like i'm definitely making a mistake somewhere in the test. And I'm not sure what's right or wrong at this point. The codes for code, test, and snapshot is posted below.

If anyone can help and point me in the direction would be greatly appreciated.

Checkbox.js

```
const styles = {
  checkbox: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: 100,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
};

const Checkbox = ({ label, checked, onChange, style }) => (
  <label style={{ ...styles.checkbox, ...style }}>
    <input checked={checked} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} />
    {label}
  </label>
);
```

Checkbox.test.js

```
const label = 'Checkbox Test';
const checked = false;
const onChange = jest.fn();

describe('Checkbox', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const cbTest = shallow(
    <Checkbox>
    <label style={{ ...styles.checkbox }}>
    <input checked={checked} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} /> 
    {label}
    </label>
    </Checkbox>);
    expect(cbTest).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

snapshot

```
exports[`Checkbox renders correctly 1`] = `
<label
  style={
    Object {
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "fontSize": 14,
      "fontWeight": 100,
    }
  }
>
  <input
    checked={undefined}
    onChange={undefined}
    type="checkbox"
  />

</label>
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its cause you dont pass the props to the `Checkbox` component

```
const label = 'Checkbox Test';
const checked = false;
const onChange = jest.fn();

describe('Checkbox', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const cbTest = shallow(
    <Checkbox 
      checked={checked} 
      styles={styles} 
      onChange={onChange} 
      label="someLabel" />
    expect(cbTest).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: oh, so the props are passed this way in the test? thank you!

Comment: Its like you would use in your app.

Comment: i want to simulate a click on the checkbox for a test, should i do something like const label = wrapper.find('label');  label.simulate('click'); ?